# Floor(X) modulo X equals X?

Tags: java

quick question.
I'm basically working on a program where we have an Entity cross across a grid. Every time it finishes a "step" (ie, goes from (0, 0) to (1, 0)), I need to fire off an event. The entity's movement per frame is calculated by:

```
frameMovement = entitySpeed * (frameDeltaMs / 1000)
```

and then added onto the entity's X co-ordinate. I elected to use world units (1 world unit is 16 pixels) instead of raw pixels for the co-ordinate system simply for separation of concern. The world does not need to know that the distance for one square is 16 pixels - only the drawing system does.

So basically, I'm trying to work out how to tell the system that the unit has finished a "step". Obviously, due to the way the frame movement is calculated, you will never be exactly on a new square, so I must "clip" the unit to that square or have a method that will return "true" if we are within a certain distance from the square (which right now I have decided to be 0.05wu - about 0.8 pixels from the square).

The function I have so far is this:

```
return Math.floor(x) % x == 0;
```

I'm only using X seeing as I'm just trying to get it working at the moment. However the problem I have is that this function seems to return one of two results:

```
x = 0f;
System.out.println(Math.floor(x) % x);
> NaN
```

This is to be expected, as 0 % 0 is indeed NaN. I can work around this no problem. However the issue I have at the moment is the other result..

```
x = 1f; // Or any number with 1sd > 0
System.out.println(Math.floor(x) % x);
> 1f
```

That is, the other result always returns the value of X, rather than the correct modulo (which, if math.floor(x) and x are equal - ie x is equal to 1f), which should be 0.

I'm not entirely sure what is causing this. If you have any answers for me or any suggestions on how I can fix this in a better way, I'm all ears.

TL;DR: I need to figure out when an Entity moves from one co-ordinate to the next. The co-ordinates (and the Entity's transition across them) are stored as a float. If an Entity is halfway across traversing a square, the Entity's X co-ordinate is stored as 1.5, for example. Finally, Floor(1.0) % 1.0 is returning 1.0, and not 0.

EDIT:

In my code I have this

```
    System.out.println("x equals " + x + ". Math.floor(x)%x==Math.floor(x): "+(Math.floor(x)%x==Math.floor(x)));
```

With output http://pastebin.com/egDwj7Gs

EDIT 2:
Images are fun!

http://prntscr.com/1j193n

The white square is the entity. The red square is simply a drawn-on grid. Each square is 16 by 16.

As you can see, right now the white square is at (6.5, 0). I need the program to basically recognise when it passes (7, 0).

EDIT: Lee and I had a chat, here's our chat:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34727/discussion-between-neglected-and-lee-meador

He solved the problem for me so I have accepted his answer as correct.

```
        float after = pos.x+changeInPosition;

        if (Math.floor(after) != Math.floor(pos.x)) {
            // We passed a boundary
        }
        pos.x = after;
```

Comment: y % x can never equal x. It can equal anything from 0 to x-1.

Comment: in my code I have this:   System.out.println(Math.floor(x) % x == Math.floor(x));
and it is evaluating true. I'm aware it **should** never equal it, but the problem I'm having is that it **does**.

Comment: Evaluates to false for me.

Comment: Try cleaning and recompiling your project. Maybe you are running old code?

Comment: Cleaned it, and I'm still getting this: http://pastebin.com/egDwj7Gs

Comment: You have an `&` where a `%` should be.

Comment: ^ Typo, my bad :P But that's not present in the code.

Comment: Do your squares have world coordinates too? i.e. width and height?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question, yes, each square on the grid has a world co-ordinate (or will, at least!)

Comment: Your mod seems to be the wrong way around. `x % y = Remainder(x/y)`. If x=2.1, your formula calculates `2 % 2.1` -- i.e., always the *left* value. (Which does not, by the way, explains your problem with `1f`. I think all you need is `Math.round` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modulo means we divide and take the remainder (just like in 3rd grade for me).

So ...

```
10 % 9 is 1.
```

And

```
10 % 10 is 0
```

And

```
10.5 % 10.5 is 0.
```

(Perhaps you could get rounding issues if you had x = ...calculate 10.5.. and then x % x where you would get a number just below 10.5 or just larger than 0.)

So, for all integers,

```
Floor(x) % x is 0.
```

For a non-integer, it works differently.

```
Floor(10.5) => 10
```

and

```
10 % 10.5 is 10.
```

So barring the effect of rounding errors in the floating point, Floor(x) % x is either 0 (for integers) or Floor(x) for non-integers.

**More**

Perhaps you could tell if it passed a grid line by comparing the before and after positions:

```
if (Math.Floor(xAfterMoving / gridSize) != Math.floor(xBeforeMoving / gridSize)) {
    fireXGridCrossingEvent();
}
```

Comment: Hm. In my school I was never taught modulus. I just knew it returned the remainder of a division equation. what do you suggest I use instead, then? I just need to verify if (or if not) the entity is on a square or not. The only alternative I can think of is using pixels as measurement but that seems like a pretty bad idea.

Comment: I tried this, and, er, well, it triggers every time the entity moves, not necessarily when it crosses a boundary.

Comment: Also, the Movement system does not have any knowledge of how big each grid square is. It only knows that 1 co-ordinate change means you've crossed a square entirely. :P

Comment: I don't see how a sub-system can tell if you crossed from one grid area to another without knowing details about the grid system. Perhaps the movement system can just fire an event for any move and pass the before and after coordinates. Some other part can listen and detect the grid crossings.

Comment: The movement system knows that each world-unit increment means you have gone across a new boundary, as it were. I can easily fire off an event (for lack of a better word) if it does cross a boundary, I just need to find an equation for it to go "oh, you crossed a boundary).

That is, the movement system knows that if you go from (0, 0) to (1,0) (and it has access to those coordinates per entity), that you've moved into a new square.

Comment: You can't count on it landing right on the line. In other words, you can't count of the x or y value getting a particular integer value while crossing that grid line.

Comment: Exactly. I was going to add a "tolerance" parameter in after I worked this out, of around 0.05 - 0.1 world units (equates to around .8 of a pixel).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34727/discussion-between-neglected-and-lee-meador)

Comment: Are the "world movement" increments the integers? Another way to say it is, are the boundaries just all integers? Or I could ask the same question as, are the grid lines at 1, 2, 3, etc on the world-unit scale?